# How to get cheapest product from every group

Tags: laravel

How to do the following with laravel ORM?

```
select f.type, f.variety, f.price
from (
 select type, min(price) as minprice
 from fruits group by type
 ) as x inner join fruits as f on f.type = x.type and f.price = x.minprice;
```

Comment: Please add detail about your models and relations.

Comment: Fruits table with columns type, variety and price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$subQuery = "(select type, min(price) as minprice from fruits group by type) as x";
$query = DB::table('fruits')::selectRaw( "fruits.type,fruits.variety,x.minprice" );
$query->join( DB::raw($subQuery), function ($join) {
    $join->on ( 'fruits.type', '=', 'x.type' );
});
$data = $query->get();
```

I have not tested the code but hopes it works.

Comment: Thank you! It worked. I hade to join on minprice too. $join->on('fruits.price', x.price).